# Raspberry Pi Pico W bad SCL Pin error (Micropython)

Tags: raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to output the temperature values from a DHT20 temperature sensor via a raspberry pi pico w. I have connected the sda and scl pins of the sensor to pins 11 and 12 of the pi pico respectively.

Here is the following code I am trying to run:

```
import machine
from machine import Pin, I2C
from utime import sleep

from dht20 import DHT20


i2c0_sda = Pin(2) #11 or 8 or 4
i2c0_scl = Pin(2) #12 or 9 or 5
i2c0 = machine.I2C(id=1, sda=i2c0_sda, scl=i2c0_scl) #this is line 10

dht20 = DHT20(0x38, i2c0)

while True:
    measurements = dht20.measurements
    print(f"Temperature: {measurements['t']} °C, humidity: {measurements['rh']} %RH")
    sleep(1)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
ValueError: bad SCL pin
```

Does anyone know why this is occuring? I have verified the correct wiring and tried a new breadboard as well.

Comment: Well, you certainly can't use *the same pin* for both SDA and SCL!  8 and 9 are the correct GPIO numbers for physical pins 11 and 12 - but those pins are only options for the I2C0 port, rather than I2C1, so you'd need to change your `id` value to match.